# Updating a counter without reloading the entire page in Scala Play

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm building an app in Scala Play MVC that has posts. These posts have an upvote counter and can be upvoted and downvoted.
The posts are just kept in memory.
I want the visual counter on the page to update when a vote happens, and the count on the post object simultaniously.

I only know how to do this with rerendering the entire page, sending a request and receiving the same view.
Is this possible with twirl parameters in Play, preferably without Ajax or Javascript?

Comment: Your question is too broad to be easily answered. But keep in mind that Play is just a server though, it can do whatever you want but on the server side. Of you want to do stuff client side you have to write JavaScript (served by Play optionally).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.